# How do I allow Windows Authentication in ASP.NET MVC4 application with multiple domains?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc-4, windows-authentication, intranet

Two questions regarding Windows Auth in MVC4 application:

1. How to I set it up so I can authenticate against two windows domains?

What I am trying to do:

```
[Authorize(Roles = @"DOMAINONE\Group Name")]
public class HomeController : Controller
{
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        return View();
    }
    ...
}
```

And the other domain:

```
[Authorize(Roles = @"DOMAINTWO\Group Name")]
public class StaffController : Controller
{
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        return View();
    }
    ...
}
```

1. Is there a way to make to login screen an form on a page, rather than the pop-up window asking for a username/password?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

May be you would like to see the mix of Windows and forms authentication : *Is there a way to make to login screen an form on a page, rather than the pop-up window asking for a username/password?*

If you're in classic mode - you can have both  Windows and Forms authentication. An alert will pop up

```
Challenge-based and login redirect-based authentication cannot be used 
simultaneously
```

you can however ignore this warning.  CarlosAg says that:

```
we decided to leave it there was because it is still behavior that many user 
scenarios  would be consider incorrect, since most of the time forms 
authentication  uses anonymous  authentication and not windows.
```

Read [here.](http://forums.iis.net/t/1174844.aspx)

Now when you want to use windows authentication, you may find solution here: http://mvolo.com/iis-70-twolevel-authentication-with-forms-authentication-and-windows-authentication/, which allows to change the authentication way for a page.
Another way you can manage this when using windows authentication is to manage usernames using code:

```
string user = Request.ServerVariables["LOGON_USER"];
```

Refer this link: http://beensoft.blogspot.in/2008/06/mixing-forms-and-windows-authentication.html , which gives a different way of mixing Forms and Windows authentication.

Comment: Thanks for the links, I think this points me in the direction I want to be going, which is SSO, more or less.

Answer (score 1):

The first thing you need to do is set your authentication mode in web.config if you haven't already.

```
<system.web>
  <authentication mode="Windows"/>
</system.web>
```

This should eliminate the challenge provided the user is already authenticated in his/her domain.

Are DOMAINONE and DOMAINTWO subdomains of the same domain?