# Dual authentication mode

Tags: asp.net, authentication, iis-7

people

I am looking for a long time and have not found a way to make a double authentication in asp.net(4.0, 4.5) website in IIS 7, 7.5.

Windows authentication for INTRANET users

and

Forms authentication for INTERNET users

is it possible?? someone already did??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is possible technically.

The classic Mode doesn't requires much effort and can be implemented more or less easily. However when in integrated mode , some careful work is required to achieve the same.

Check one post  [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17934715/how-do-i-allow-windows-authentication-in-asp-net-mvc4-application-with-multiple/17936950#17936950) which may be of help to you for getting started.