# Connecting ASP.NET MVC Web App to use Windows credentials for user login?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, windows, security, owin

I'm trying to build an ASP.NET MVC5 site for intranet use. I need to install it on a server and connect the login form to use Windows credentials for users logging into the site. Its  a large corporation with several levels of IT and Security to get through for anything 'special', so I'm looking for simple and no change requests if possible.

I've been searching and reading online for several days, run through the Visual Studio wizards, tried various configurations, researched the IdenitityStoreManager and IdentityAuthenticationManager interfaces ...

I can easily build the site to use individual accounts, which seems to have the behavior I want, except that it wires in a database. I don't want the database, I want it to use the Windows/Domain credentials for access.

I've found lots of info about hooking up to AD/ADFS in Azure, and even a little for On-Premises, but it seems far heavier than I want. I'm guessing I can do what I want in a little bit of configuration magic, but ?

Are there any good examples or blogs available for this specific usage ?

Comment: Just googling "Windows Authentication MVC 5" has brought up a bunch of useful links. Here is one that should help get you started. http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/770347/On-Premise-Application-Identity-Windows-Authentica

Comment: Thanks! That looks like the piece I was missing for some of the AD setup. However the other part I'm trying to sort out is with Windows auth, when I navigate to the site I get a windows dialog to enter credentials. I'd like to see an example where I can use the web site pages to enter the credentials, so I can do some branding/styling on the login.

Comment: I believe if you use IE that popup doesn't show as it uses the logged in users credentials. Check this link, it seems like it kinda explains how to manually do it. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17934715/how-do-i-allow-windows-authentication-in-asp-net-mvc4-application-with-multiple

Answer (score 0):

Google found lots of [answers](https://www.google.ru/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&ion=1&espv=2&ie=UTF-8#newwindow=1&safe=off&q=asp%20net%20mvc%20authentication%20windows)

For example [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg703322(VS.98).aspx) one is good enought, it's about MVC 3, but it's the basics of this subject

Main configuration is happened in web.config file:

```
<authentication mode="Windows">
</authentication>
```

Comment: Thanks! I walked through the example. I can turn on the Windows Authentication. When I deploy it to a server and use an external browser, I get a Windows login dialog. I'd like to have a login page that I can style, but have it tie into the windows authentication backend. Have you seen anything like that?

Comment: Login page for already authentificated users? There is another solution. You can create custom Identity and check users by your DB tables.